# Python : replace multiple occurrence of characater by one but single occurrence by none

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting

I have a string:

```
a = '0202201131181'
```

I want to replace all multiple occurrences of `1` in `a` if present, by a single `1` but if only one occurrence of '1' is found then replace it by empty string ''.

My end goal is to get:

```
a = '0202201318'
```

Here the '1' after character '8' is occurring only once, so it's replaced by empty string, but the '11' before the character '3' and after the character, '3' is replaced by '1'.

Here is an if-else code block I tried, which is partially correct:

```
if '11' in a:
    a = a.replace("11","1")
else:
    a = a.replace("1","")
```

But it outputs `'02022013181'`, which is incorrect. How to do this?

Comment: Can you have more than 2 ones at a stretch?

Comment: @TaohidulIslam yes, another sample may be `a = '020220111311811'`, in which case, the desired output would be `a = '02022013181'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regex is probably the best option:

```
import re

a = '020220111311811001001001001'

a = re.sub(r'1{2,}', '1', re.sub(r'(?<!1)1(?=[^1]|$)', '', a))
print(a)
```

First sub out single `1`s, then sub out multiple occurrences of `1`. I added some more characters to `a` for testing purposes, and the output is

```
0202201318100000000
```

If you don't like the somewhat confusion caused by the one-liner:

```
a = re.sub(r'(?<!1)1(?=[^1]|$)', '', a)
a = re.sub(r'1{2,}', '1', a)
```

Explanation of `(?<!1)1(?=[^1]|$)`:

- `(?<!1)`: Make sure the character before is not a `1`.
- `1`: Literally match a `1`.
- `(?=[^1]|$)`: Make sure the character ahead is either a) not a `1`, or b) is the end of the string.

Comment: Upvoted. I think second regex should be `1{1,1}` - much easier and much faster. Also, I would implement the 2 replacements as 2 consecutive statements - a lot more visible what is going on.

Comment: @virolino That would be great if it were that simple, unfortunately such a pattern (which can further be reduced to just `1`) will match strings like `11` twice... About the readability thing, I'm just a big fan of one-liners, what can I say? :)

Comment: hmm... you seem to be right about the 1st part. About the second, I also like 1-liners when it does not break readability - and when they do not add unneeded complexity. In this case, it is more like obfuscation - my 2 cents :)

Comment: :))) Thank you - 2 lines look better :D

Comment: `a = re.sub(r'`([^1])1([^1])`', '\1\2', a)` does it work? In my mind, it should...

Comment: @virolino How about start/end of strings? Also, try it with `01010`.

Comment: `\1` is the first ([^1]) and `\2` is the second ([^1]). First sub should be this: (^|[^1])1([^1]|$) - otherwise fails if 1 is at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: @PIG Which one do you mean? The one that subs the single `1`s or the one that subs the multiple `1`s?

Comment: Tricky - my ego has to admit defeat - at least for the moment :)

Comment: @virolino It's still not catching all of the `1`s... See https://regex101.com/r/p46DWW/1

Comment: this one re.sub(r'(?<!1)1(?=[^1]|$)'

Comment: that is where I tested myself - before admitting defeat. For the moment, look ahead and look behind are better ;) Thanks for the challenge, though.

Comment: @PIG `(?<!1)`: Make sure the character before is not a `1`. `1`: Literally match a `1`. `(?=[^1]|$)`: Make sure the character ahead is either a) not a `1`, or b) is the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Regex based solution is the best. No two thoughts on that.

Just a another logic without using regular expressions, just for the record:

```
a = '110202201111311811'
new_str = []

for i in range(len(a)):
   if a[i] == '1':
       if (i!= (len(a)-1) and a[i+1] == '1') and (i!=0 and a[i-1] != '1'):
           new_str.append(a[i])
   else:
       new_str.append(a[i])

print ("".join(x for x in new_str))
```

**Output:**

```
02022013181
```

Comment: Almost like a bubble-sort for regexes :) But if regexes are not an option, we have to deal with it, true.

Comment: @virolino, True. Having another option doesn't hurt. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to achieve the expected output without using regex.
What I am doing is, I am splitting the string from '11' and the replacing all the '1's with empty space and joining the list into string with '1' again.

```
a = '0202201131181'
tmp =[ i.replace('1', '') for i in a.split('11')]
print(('1').join(tmp))
```

Breakdown of the list comprehension:

```
a = '0202201131181'
tmp =[]

for i in a.split('11'):
  i = i.replace('1','')
  tmp.append(i)

print(('1').join(tmp))
```

Comment: it will not work when there are more than two 1's consecutively . a = '0202201131181111'

Comment: @PIG it will replace last 2 pairs with '11' if the OP wants to do recursive operation then it will need one more revision to get the final result. Otherwise as per the current conditions, I guess it is right as it gives "020220131811" as final result.

Answer (score 0):

Non-regex solution, inspired by @Jay. I have zero knowledge of Python, so syntax probably needs alteration. Of course, not tested. "Benefit": conditions are less complicated (I hope).

```
a = '110202201111311811'
new_str = []

while (not end of string) :
    while ((a[i]!='1') and (not end of string))
        new_str.append(a[i])
        i++

    if (a[i+1] is not out of range ) and (a[i+1] != '1') :
        i++
    else :
        new_str.append(a[i])
        while a[i]=='1' :
            i++

print ("".join(x for x in new_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '111020220113111111'
while a.find('11') != -1:
  i = 0
  j = 1
  while i < len(a):
    for c in a:
        if a[i] == '1':
            if a[j] == '1':
                a = a.replace(a[i],'x')
    i = i + 1
    j = i + 1
  a = a.replace("xx","1")
  a = a.replace("x","1")
print(a)
```

I tried the following few cases with the above code:

```
a = '111020220113111111'          >> 1020220131
a = '020220111311811001001001001' >> 02022013181001001001001
a = '0202201131181'               >> 02022013181
```

NOTE: Edited my earlier code.